# Program on an Android mobile device

Tags: android, programming-languages, android-2.2-froyo

I'm looking for a way to code on a Galaxy Tab, running Android 2.2. I'm not very particular on the language, as long as it can do loops, random number generation, and output. Is there a way to currently do this?

Comment: Whats your question? Do you want a compiler for android or something?

Comment: Yeah, a compiler that runs on android.

Comment: /facepalm at people not reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "development on the go" and you don't care about the language take a look at [JRuby for Android](http://code.google.com/p/jruby-for-android/). Its more for scripts but it may fit the bill for your question. Alternatively use ConnectBot to SSH into your own server for doing development work but does require a data connection.

Answer (score 2):

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do Get the galaxy emulator and follow the step to develop on galaxt tab.

But before doing that visit http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

Hope this helps u get started development on android, particularly on Galaxy Tab

Comment: I like the Galaxy emulator :)

Comment: me too. but im waiting that the galaxy sdk to come bundled with maps

Answer (score 0):

Check out developer.Android.com , there you should be able to find a good start on writing code for Android devices.

Comment: Whoops, missed you're comment. Don't know of any compilers that run on Android, but it would be cool have one.

Answer (score -1):

You got full Java SE at your disposal.

Comment: How can I access it? Is there a sort of mobile version of Eclipse?

Comment: everything you need to know is right here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Nope, Android doesn't support full Java SE